# Twilio voice conference time out

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

We are using Twilio's conference call for creating calls between different parties.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-create-conference-calls

Is there a way in which, if, participant A starts a conference call and no other participants join the call within say, 5 minutes, the conference call gets terminated?

I can run a timer on the initiator's end and close the conference but i was looking for a cleaner solution. Something like, a timeout on the conference call itself.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There's no time out on a conference like you describe, so your best bet is to run the timer on your side and cancel it if another participant joins the conference.

Comment: We are using this tutorial as reference: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/warm-transfer-php-laravel, but on this step:

"4. The client stays on hold while the first agent joins the call"

We would like to get a voicemail from the original caller if no agent joins the conference, is that possible?

Comment: @CarlosMafla sure, you'd have to run a timer on your application that you would cancel if the agent joins the conference. And if the timer completes, then you make a request to the API to update the client's call to new TwiML that would `<Record>` the voicemail.